# formula for minimum colsample value in XGBoost

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, hyperparameters

On the documentation for [XGBoost parameters](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html) it says:

> colsample_by* parameters work cumulatively. For instance, the combination {'colsample_bytree':0.5, 'colsample_bylevel':0.5, 'colsample_bynode':0.5} with 64 features will leave 8 features to choose from at each split.

With this in mind, does the following formula make sense to determine the minimum possible colsample* values when attempting hyperparameter optimization?

> (features * (x^3)) = 1